# How to access DOM element outside of ion-content view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, dom, getelementbyid

Running an Ionic v1 app, in my template page I have:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-title>
    <div id="navTitle"></div>
  </ion-nav-title>

  <ion-content>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

From the view controller, I am trying to get the div element with: `var el = document.getElementById("navTitle");`  but its errors indicating the `el` is null.  It seems ionic can't see elements outside of the `ion-content`

How can I get the element?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Turns out I needed to add a slight delay to a function that was being called when the controller was entered.  The function was trying to access the dom element before it was set in the `ion-nav-title` section.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   doFunction() ;
},500) ;
```

Its not ideal, but it did the trick

**UPDATE**:
I found a better way.  Elements outside of the `ion-content` should be assigned an ng-model, and then the model can be accessed from the normal scope:

```
<div id="navTitle" ng-model="$parent.navTitle"></div>
<ion-content>
   ...
</ion-content>
```

Then in the controller, it can accessed with `$scope.navTitle`